# Finding continuous bijections between these funtions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} (3n ,3n+1) \bigcup \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}${3n+2} and $Y =(0,1]  \bigcup \bigcup_{n=1}(3n, 3n+1) \bigcup \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} $ {3n+2} be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$  with usual subspace topology.

Then:
(a) Prove that there is a continuous bijection f : X-> Y.

(b) Prove that there is a continuous bijection from Y-> X.

For (b) I took f(x)=x. but This is not continuous. For (a) this will not work due to 1 $\in Y$ and I am not able to think of such a function for (a).But I can take f(x) =x/2 except for the points with {3n+2} where  I can take f(x)= x.

But I am not able to solve the problem of continuity.

Thanks!

Comment: No demand on $f$ in $(b)$? onto or bijection too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), map each open interval to itself, map $2$ to $1$, and map $3n+2$ to $3n-1$ for $n\ge 1$.

For (b), just set $f(y)=2$ for all $y\in Y$. (This is where you kick yourself!)

Comment: "This is where you kick yourself!" What does it mean ?

Comment: When you hit yourself on the forehead (or you kick yourself) and say "Why didn't I think of that?"

Comment: Actually in (b) there was Prove that there is a continuous "bijection" from Y-> X instead of a function from Y-> X. Can you please help me with this. I made a tpyo

Comment: I think for (b)  mapping 1->2 and 3n-1 to 3n+2 and open intervals to open intervals will work. Am I right?

Comment: @No-One: no, that is not continuous at $1$.